# Design verification - chat application architecture

Tags: java, architecture, messaging

So for my newest hobby project, I want to create a simple chat application where users can just log in with a nickname (no passwords) and talk to anybody on the network.

Off the top of my head, I'm thinking about this design where a frontend `Client` acquires a `User` object by registering with a nickname.

A `Message` object can behave like packets in the network, with a `Postman` delivering a given `Message` object to the intended recipient.

When a user sends a message, they call:

```
    postman.addMessage(message);
```

and the `Postman` then delivers this to the `inTray` located in `Server`.

The receiver's `Postman` eventually finds a `Message` object intended for them in the `outTray` and fetches it for its `Client`.

[image: Chat - UML Diagram]

Any thoughts on the design? For all I know, it probably sucks but some constructive criticism is always welcome.

Comment: Your question is a design and architecture question so Frank was incorrect.  These types of questions are more than welcome here orion_ix.

Comment: @maple_shaft very good to know - saved me some time there.

Comment: This *could* be on-topic, but what is the actual question? "Thoughts on the design" and "constructive criticism" seem like an invitation to debate, which is off-topic here...

Comment: @AndresF. the answer by Christophe below is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your explanations, the user interacts with a postman to send and receive messages, which are stored on a server.

That's a good start.  But I'm not sure that the class diagram fully reflects your explanations;  It also raises some questions:

- the user would be "composed" of several clients ??  I thought that the user user would register to a client. Or eventually that a client would own several users.
- is the client supposed to represent the user interface ?
- the postman would be composed of several users ??  Do you mean that a postman serves several users.  And what is the relationship between a postman a client and a server ?
- are the intray/outray on the sever organized by postman ? by user ? or is it global for the all the users/postman ?
- are messages stored twice on the server: in outray (send by user) and in the intray (adressed to user) ?
- when the message is sent to the server, is a copy kept in the postman ?  when a message is retrieved from the server, is it removed there ?
- the notion of user session is not represented here.  What if a user logs off, and logs in later ?  What will happens to the messages that he has received in the meantime ? will the same postman always serve the same user ?

As you can see above, you are very much at the beginning of your design. Without addressing all these points, I'd already propose you a reviewed diagram:

[image]

Some key aspects:

- There is no permanent relation between postman and server: a posman is not structurally related to a server.  There is only a dependency, because when a postman is told to connect with a server, he has to know the interface of the server (yet to be defined)
- The messages are either stored in a postman, or on a server (see the black diamonds).
- there is a link to be clarified between a user and a postman (e.g. the user has a link to the postman, or the postman has a list of users).
- there is a link to be clarified beteween a user and a ClientUI.  As the user seems to be created when connecting to UI, we could imagine that the User is created by the UI.
- it has to be clarified how the servers are managed:  does every client manage a server ?  Is teh server given when login ? Are server operated independently ?  are server searched via a network protocol by the postman when he needs it ? You need to clarify this.

Comment: This is excellent stuff - really made me think about my design and reconsider some things. Thanks a bunch!